# LINQ query filters not returning correct number of results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search form with many filter fields. First I get all fields to a var like:

```
var obj = (from kb in db.kimlik_bilgileri
            join dbilgi in db.dil_bilgisi on kb.id equals dbilgi.KimlikId
            join okbil in db.okul_bilgileri on kb.id equals okbil.KimlikId
            join kurbil in db.kurum_bilgileri on kb.id equals kurbil.KimlikId
            join ens in db.enstitu on kurbil.kurum_id equals ens.id
            join kadr in db.kadro_unvan on kurbil.kadro_id equals kadr.id
            where kb.Aktifmi == true select new PSearchModel
                    {
                        DilBilgisi = dbilgi,
                        // Diller =  dil,
                        OkulBilgileri = okbil,
                        KadroUnvan = kadr,
                        Enstitu = ens,
                        KimlikBilgileri = kb,
                        KurumBilgileri = kurbil
                    }).ToList();
```

After this, I tried to start filtering by fields like:

```
if (!yabanciDil.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{

    obj = (from o in obj
        where o.DilBilgisi.dil_id == Convert.ToInt32(yabanciDil)
           select new PSearchModel
           {
               DilBilgisi = o.DilBilgisi,
               KadroUnvan = o.KadroUnvan,
               KimlikBilgileri = o.KimlikBilgileri,
               OkulBilgileri = o.OkulBilgileri,
               // Diller = o.Diller,
               Enstitu = o.Enstitu,
               KurumBilgileri = o.KurumBilgileri

           }).ToList();
}
```

First `obj` count with 2k data which I expected, but second filter returned count 0. I have 4 or 5 filters also to apply. What did I do wrong or anyone with this condition can describe this.

Comment: you can select, order and group a list with LINQ like this:
yourVarVariable.WHERE(m=>m.dil_id=123)

Comment: note: if `db.` here is a data-context (EF, LINQ-to-SQL, etc) - then that first `.ToList()` is going to *execute* the query, and the second filter only happens in local memory rather than at the database - that might be important if the second query is meant to reduce to amount of data transferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the approach for filtering data like this is with cumulative query composition; for example:

```
IQueryable<PSearchModel> query =
    from kb in db.kimlik_bilgileri
    join dbilgi in db.dil_bilgisi on kb.id equals dbilgi.KimlikId
    join okbil in db.okul_bilgileri on kb.id equals okbil.KimlikId
    join kurbil in db.kurum_bilgileri on kb.id equals kurbil.KimlikId
    join ens in db.enstitu on kurbil.kurum_id equals ens.id
    join kadr in db.kadro_unvan on kurbil.kadro_id equals kadr.id
    where kb.Aktifmi == true
    select new PSearchModel
    {
        DilBilgisi = dbilgi,
        // Diller =  dil,
        OkulBilgileri = okbil,
        KadroUnvan = kadr,
        Enstitu = ens,
        KimlikBilgileri = kb,
        KurumBilgileri = kurbil
    };

if (!yabanciDil.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    int dil_di = Convert.ToInt32(yabanciDil);
    query = query.Where(o => o.DilBilgisi.dil_id == dil_di);
}
// ... add other filters here

var list = query.ToList();
```

This defers all execution to the end, and allows you to inspect `dil_di` when debugging, to see if it is what you expect. If you *still* don't get what you expect, then you'll have to investigate what SQL is being issued, to see why your results are different from your expectations.

Comment: Well done  and thank you very much for all sharers. Done by Marc Gravell's tech.

Answer (score 1):

You could search in your List with LINQ as well.
One possibility is this:

```
YourListObject.Where(c=>c.Test.Equals("Hallo"))
```

Also possible to Order or Group by equivalent to this.